# RSA decrypt with Java

Tags: java, rsa, encryption, private-key

I am trying to decrypt a string with RSA. It was encrypted in C# on the iPhone and I have the private key.  This seems like a silly problem, but all of the examples I have seen show generating the private key.  I have the private key (it is a byte[] of hex).  It using PKCS#1 padding.  The part I cannot figure out how to do is create a java.security.Key object with the private key I already have.

Do I need to have them give me the private key in 2 parts...modulus and exponent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're going to need some more information -- there are a bunch of ways the key could be represented. DER? PEM? PKCS#8?

Comment: It is using PKCS#1 padding...that should just change the Cipher instance though, right?

Comment: Also, the private key may itself be encrypted (this is pretty common), in which case you'd need to know the encrypting algorithm and passphrase.

Comment: So you've got a binary ASN.1 blob then? (If you're not sure, try running it through `dumpasn1` or `openssl dumpasn1 -inform DER` first.)

Comment: ...derh, that should have been `openssl asn1parse -inform DER`, brainfart.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go through a RSAPrivateKeySpec. Here's an example (based on [this](http://www.codase.com/search/call?owner=java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec)):

```
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger(nBytes);
        BigInteger p = new BigInteger(pBytes);
        RSAPrivateKeySpec privateSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(n, p);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        Key privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(privateSpec);
```

Comment: I guess my problem is that I was given the private key as a byte array in hex...0x12, 0xe3, etc.  I guess the solution is that I need the modulus and exponent.

Comment: Actually, it looks like SshRsaPrivateKey from the library you linked has an appropriate constructor. http://www.codase.com/search/display?file=L2dlbnRvbzIvdmFyL3RtcC9yZXBvcy9zb3VyY2Vmb3JnZS9zc2h0b29scy9qMnNzaC0wXzJfNy1zcmNfemlwL2oyc3NoL3NyYy9jb20vc3NodG9vbHMvajJzc2gvdHJhbnNwb3J0L3B1YmxpY2tleS9yc2EvU3NoUnNhUHJpdmF0ZUtleS5qYXZh&lang=java&off=2719+2746+

Comment: So, it does...I will give it a try.  Thanks for the help Meredith and Laurence.