# How can I generate valid RSA 1024 bits public and private keys by specifying different inputs in java?

Tags: java, rsa

(if you're coming new to the question, jump to the **EDIT, EDIT** section)

I can generate random valid RSA 1024 bit public and private keys by using the following code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");    
keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKeyGenerated = keyPair.getPublic(); //Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
PrivateKey privateKeyGenerated = keyPair.getPrivate(); //sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@fffbfe07
```

The comments in the above code give the details from the debugger.

Rather than randomly generating the public and private keys I'd like to specify inputs to generate valid keys. Something like ([link](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/sun/security/provider/DSAKeyPairGenerator.java.html) which is in the comments below):

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
BigInteger p = new BigInteger("41");
BigInteger q = new BigInteger("13");
BigInteger g = new BigInteger("17");
//http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/sun/security/provider/DSAKeyPairGenerator.java.html
//copying the methods generateKeyPair, generateX, generateY
KeyPair keyPair = generateKeyPair(p, q, g, secureRandom);
PublicKey publicKeyGenerated = keyPair.getPublic(); //Sun DSA Public Key
PrivateKey privateKeyGenerated = keyPair.getPrivate(); //DSAPrivateKey@fffa5e6a
```

Using the above code I don't get valid RSA keys like in my first example.

How can I generate my own valid RSA 1024 bit public and private keys by specifying different inputs in java?

**EDIT**, in response to Robert:

Yes, I wish to create public and private keys using user defined values, not random. In response to the link you provided I wrote this:

```
BigInteger q = new BigInteger("114...15741");  //big prime number
BigInteger g = new BigInteger("65537"); //modulus
RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(q, g);
RSAPrivateKeySpec privateSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(q, g);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(publicSpec);
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(privateSpec);
```

I created random keys then put the values for the exponent and modulus I got for the public key in the variables *q* and *g* above. I get the same public key but I don't get the same private key. I tried adding another large prime, instead of *q* but I'm not really getting the answer I'd expect. The debugger shows a difference. How do I create a valid public and private key?

**EDIT**, **EDIT**, after response to mnistic

To pull things a bit more together

```
//randomly generate public and private keys
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");    
keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKeyGenerated = keyPair.getPublic(); //Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
PrivateKey privateKeyGenerated = keyPair.getPrivate(); //sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@fffbfe07

//pull out the exponents and modulus
BigInteger publicExponent = ((RSAPublicKey)keyPair.getPublic()).getPublicExponent();
BigInteger privateExponent = ((RSAPrivateKey)keyPair.getPrivate()).getPrivateExponent();
BigInteger modulus = ((RSAPublicKey)keyPair.getPublic()).getModulus();

//generate public and private keys using the above details
RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
RSAPrivateKeySpec privateSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privateExponent);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(publicSpec);
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(privateSpec);

//check to see that the keys are the same
System.out.println((new BigInteger(publicKeyGenerated.getEncoded())).toString());
System.out.println((new BigInteger(publicKey.getEncoded())).toString());
System.out.println((new BigInteger(privateKeyGenerated.getEncoded())).toString());
System.out.println((new BigInteger(privateKey.getEncoded())).toString());
//the private keys are different :(
```

The private keys are different, what's happening here?

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to understand. Can it be that you want to create a key (not generate a random key) using existing values? If yes see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1236514/150978). BTW: the second code creates a DSA key, not RSA - that is a totally different algorithm that also uses Public-/PrivateKeys.

Comment: Yes, I wish to create keys, not randomly generate them. I've included an edit in the original post so that I could include code.

Comment: In particular in DSA p,q,g are 'domain' (group) parameters, NOT keys, and the p,q there are radically different from the ones for RSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the public exponent to both `RSAPublicKeySpec` and `RSAPrivateKeySpec`, which is wrong. `RSAPrivateKeySpec` expects the private exponent. If you want to regenerate the key from your first code snippet, you can obtain the modulus and the exponents with:

```
BigInteger publicExponent = ((RSAPublicKey)keyPair.getPublic()).getPublicExponent();
BigInteger privateExponent = ((RSAPrivateKey)keyPair.getPrivate()).getPrivateExponent();
BigInteger modulus = ((RSAPublicKey)keyPair.getPublic()).getModulus();
```

And then regenerate the key with:

```
RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
RSAPrivateKeySpec privateSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privateExponent);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(publicSpec);
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(privateSpec);
```

Note: To get the private key encoding to match, you can try the following (using `RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec`:

```
BigInteger crtCoefficient = ((RSAPrivateCrtKey)keyPair.getPrivate()).getCrtCoefficient();
BigInteger primeExponentP = ((RSAPrivateCrtKey)keyPair.getPrivate()).getPrimeExponentP();
BigInteger primeExponentQ = ((RSAPrivateCrtKey)keyPair.getPrivate()).getPrimeExponentQ();
BigInteger p = ((RSAPrivateCrtKey)keyPair.getPrivate()).getPrimeP();
BigInteger q = ((RSAPrivateCrtKey)keyPair.getPrivate()).getPrimeQ();
BigInteger publicExponent = ((RSAPrivateCrtKey)keyPair.getPrivate()).getPublicExponent();
BigInteger privateExponent = ((RSAPrivateCrtKey)keyPair.getPrivate()).getPrivateExponent();
RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec crtKeySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent, privateExponent, p, q, primeExponentP, primeExponentQ, crtCoefficient);
...
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(crtKeySpec);
```

Comment: Nice reply, particularly the casting to RSAPublicKey/RSAPrivateKey to get out the exponents and modulus. The difference I was seeing when doing it the way you specified was in the debugger. For the randomly created private key I get details for *algid*, *coeff*, *d*, *e*, *encodedKey*, *key*, *n*, *p*, *pe*, *q* and *qe*, whilst for the regenerated key I only get *algid*, *d*, *endodedKey*, *key* and *n*, Presumably nothing to worry about?

Comment: I've just done a bit more checking and the private keys come out different. System.out.println((new BigInteger(privateKeyGenerated.getEncoded())).toString());System.out.println((new BigInteger(privateKey.getEncoded())).toString()); gives different answers

Comment: @user728785: although for compatibility Java supports the 1976 form of RSA privatekey with only n,d, like all software written by people who read PKCS1, or the _whole_ Wikipedia article, it prefers _and generates_ the **"Chinese Remainder" aka CRT form**. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateCrtKey.html (note I linked java 5 which is over a decade old, 6-10 are the same) and the related `spec.RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec`.

Comment: PS: converting just a `byte[]` array to `BigInteger` and then `toString` defaulting to signed decimal can in general give confusing or nearly unusable results, although the key encodings used by Java (X.509 SPKI and PKCS8 clear, both in ASN.1 DER) at least won't be negative. `new BigInteger (1/*positive*/, bytes)` then `.toString(16/*hex*/)` is usually better, or `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary` or in a pinch `Arrays.toString` (which gives a series of byte values with commas contained in `[ ]`)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thanks for your reply, but I don't understand your answer. The private keys are different, even considering Arrays.toString or even just considering the encoded message length ((approx) 635 to 315). Can you give a working code example?

Comment: @user728785 It does not matter if the key seems to be different to you. The only fact with matter is if it can be used for encryption/decryption of data processed with the freshly generated key before storage.

Comment: He is saying that Java uses CRT for RSA computation for efficiency, so the private key returned by `generateKeyPair()` is going to contain more information so its encoding is going to look different.